# What is the proper way to set a JLabel to show an image?

Tags: java, image, swing, set, jlabel

Below is a snippet where I create my ImageIcon and JLabel:

```
ImageIcon armorShopIcon = new ImageIcon("/images/armorshop.png", "Armor Shop");
JLabel armorShopLabel = new JLabel("Armor Shop", armorShopIcon, JLabel.CENTER);

object.setArmorImage(armorShopLabel);
```

Then in my object class I have a setter:

```
public void setArmorImage(JLabel label) {
    this.jLabel1 = label;
}
```

This doesn't show the image when I test my application and I was wondering if someone could point out my mistake

***EDIT***

Most of the source code:

Main:

```
public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Main() {

    initComponents();

    ImageIcon armorIcon = new ImageIcon("/images/armorshop.png", "Armor Shop");
    JLabel armorShopLabel = new JLabel("Armor Shop", armorShopIcon, JLabel.CENTER);

    ShopDisplay armorShop = new ShopDisplay();
    armorShop.setArmorImage(armorShopLabel);


        public initComponents() { /*more generated code here*/ }

    }
}
```

Display:

```
public class ShopDisplay extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /** Creates new form ShopDisplay */
    public ShopDisplay() {
        initComponents();
    } 


    //generated by the gui builder
    //initComponents
    private void initComponents() {
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel1.setText("Shop Name");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        add(jLabel1, gridBagConstraints);
    }

    //Variable declarationg
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;


    //Setter for Shop Name
    public void setArmorImage(JLabel shopLabel) {
        this.jLabel1 = shopLabel;
    }

    //other setters for
    //multiple jLabels

}
```

Comment: Start from a working [example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) and compare it to what the GUI editor has generated.

Comment: The only thing the GUI editor generated was jLabel1. I have also tried hard coding the location to the image but am not having much luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label you pass is not added to the GUI, the following method might help-

Add another JPanel as a container of `jLabel1` and only replace its content:

i.e.:

```
    private javax.swing.JPanel containerPanel;
    private void initComponents() {
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1.setText("Shop Name");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        containerPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        containerPanel.add(jLabel1);
        add(containerPanel, gridBagConstraints);
    }

    //Variable declarationg
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;


    //Setter for Shop Name
    public void setArmorImage(JLabel shopLabel) {
        containerPanel.remove(jLabel1);
        containerPanel.add(shopLabel);
        jLabel1 = shopLabel;
        revalidate();
    }
```

<strike>, if you want to add it to the gui you can do one of the following:</strike>

1. set the properties of `jLabel1` as the properties of `shopLabel`, something like `this.jLabel1.setText(shopLabel.getText());`
2. OR- remove `jLabel1`, add `shopLabel` and set `this.jLabel1` to `shopLabel`:

For example:

```
public void setArmorImage(JLabel shopLabel) {
    remove(jLabel1);
    add(shopLabel);
    jLabel1 = shopLabel;
    revalidate();
}
```

Comment: This made the image appear, but ended up placing it elsewhere on the panel. Would I have to reset the constraints before I revalidate?

Comment: @StartingGroovy - Hi, see updated answer, changed a few things that might help you.

Comment: it still seems to place it elsewhere on the view object. It places it in the place where the third jLabel is. At least the image is showing up now though :)

Comment: @StartingGroovy - there is one problem, pointed out by camickr - you need to provide us a full working program that will help us recreate the problem, I could've try to help you with spoting a specific problem, but I can't test it without (even a small) working program.

Comment: thank you for helping me out. I'm unaware of why the constraints aren't quite working the way I want after the `revalidate()` but I will continue tinkering with it. The method you have provided and the one that camickr provided both work quite nicely. Your time spent helping has been appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void setArmorImage(JLabel label)
{     
    this.jLabel1 = label; 
}
```

That code does nothing. Assigning a label reference to another variable does not affect the GUI. You need to "add(...)" the label to the GUI in order for the label to be seen.

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for working examples.

If you want to update an existing label on the GUI then you would use:

```
label.setIcon(...);
```

If you need more help post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) showing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I wasn't aware that I couldn't just reset the jLabel in that way.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for pointing out the `setIcon` method. I went ahead and tested it out and it works quite nicely

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a `JLabel` and then passing it to `setArmorImage`, which then assigns it to `jLabel1`. The question is what are you doing with `jLabel1` after its value has changed? My guess is that you're putting `jLabel1` in your container somewhere, then `setArmorImage` is called changing what `jLabel1` points to, but the old label instance (previously pointed to by `jLabel1`) is still in your container.

To fix this you'll need to remove the old label instance and put in the new one. you could make this easier by using a container (`JPanel`) that old holds your Label. Then all you need to do is swap labels from the holder.

Comment: I originally have the `jLabel1.setText("Shop Name")` but shouldn't it change to my image once I call the `setArmorImage()` I'll post some more code in just a minute. On a side note, my object that holds the jLabel is a jPanel

Comment: I appreciate the response, as a few have stated below, my setter isn't affecting the Gui which seems to be my problem

Answer (score 2):

> The only thing the GUI editor generated was `jLabel1`.

What no code in the fold? Since no one else can see your computer, start from a working [example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/zipfiles/components-LabelDemoProject.zip) that everyone can see. Unzip it, and type `ant run`. Now compare `src/components/LabelDemo.java` to your code.

Comment: Click on the button labeled [`Source`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/nb/index.html).

Comment: Well it also generated the `constraints` and `setText("Shop Name")` but I would think that it would replace the text with my new jLabel upon setting it? I'll grab the example and take a look

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard a hyperlink called a fold.

Comment: @Steve Kuo: I thought you understood that @StartingGroovy is using the NetBeans GUI editor. In this case the link is sort of a pointer-to-a-pointer: a handle, if you will. Or were you being (humorously) disingenuous?